# How to store entire $_POST variable in the session

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I have dropdown select that when I click the submit button it's displays the records base on the value of dropdown. It's works fine, but when I refresh the app_list2.php it's displays nothing. I want to stay the records that displays in app_list2.php. How I can store all the $_POST value in session ?

```
    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $drop = $_POST['drop_1'];
    $tier_two = $_POST['tier_two'];

    $where = "WHERE app_cn='$drop' AND app_plan_no='$tier_two'";

$result1 = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT *, SUM(unit_cost*quantity) AS total_amount, SUM(unit_cost*1st_quarter) AS 1st_quarter_total, SUM(unit_cost*2nd_quarter) AS 2nd_quarter_total, SUM(unit_cost*3rd_quarter) AS 3rd_quarter_total,
    SUM(unit_cost*4th_quarter) AS 4th_quarter_total, SUM((quantity)-(1st_q_qty_del+2nd_q_qty_del+3rd_q_qty_del+4th_q_qty_del)) AS balance
    FROM app 
    $where 
    GROUP BY counter ORDER BY counter
");
?>

<?php
echo'<table id="tfhover" cellspacing="0" class="tablesorter" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Fund Source</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Unit Cost</th>
    </tr>
        </thead>';
        echo'<tbody>';
$i=1;
while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
if($row['app_cn'] != '')
 {
 echo'<tr>
    <td>'.$row['item_name'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['item_description'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['fund_source'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['unit'].'</td>
        <td>'.number_format($row['unit_cost'], 2, '.', ',').'</td>
       </tr>';
    }
        }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Check for errors, seems a php error. And sanitize your query fields

Comment: no error, I think is it bcoz it has no id that determine the records?

Comment: its because on refresh , you will lost track of posted values , so nothing will appear

Comment: @leobali ur right, how I can get the posted value even I refresh the the page?

Comment: store all the post values to session

Comment: $_SESSION('post-data') = $_POST; ? Can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try out this code

```
<?php

    ob_start();
    session_start();
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");



    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //unset the session value 
    $_SESSION['content'] = '';

    $drop = $_POST['drop_1'];
    $tier_two = $_POST['tier_two'];

    $where = "WHERE app_cn='$drop' AND app_plan_no='$tier_two'";

$result1 = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT *, SUM(unit_cost*quantity) AS total_amount, SUM(unit_cost*1st_quarter) AS 1st_quarter_total, SUM(unit_cost*2nd_quarter) AS 2nd_quarter_total, SUM(unit_cost*3rd_quarter) AS 3rd_quarter_total,
    SUM(unit_cost*4th_quarter) AS 4th_quarter_total, SUM((quantity)-(1st_q_qty_del+2nd_q_qty_del+3rd_q_qty_del+4th_q_qty_del)) AS balance
    FROM app 
    $where 
    GROUP BY counter ORDER BY counter
");
?>

<?php
echo'<table id="tfhover" cellspacing="0" class="tablesorter" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Fund Source</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Unit Cost</th>
    </tr>
        </thead>';
        echo'<tbody>';
$i=1;
while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
if($row['app_cn'] != '')
 {
 echo'<tr>
    <td>'.$row['item_name'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['item_description'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['fund_source'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['unit'].'</td>
        <td>'.number_format($row['unit_cost'], 2, '.', ',').'</td>
       </tr>';
    }
        }
    echo "</tbody></table>";

    $sPageContent = ob_get_clean();
    $_SESSION['content']    =   $sPageContent;

}else{

    if (isset($_SESSION['content'])){
        echo $_SESSION['content'];
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: try to clear the cache before trying this code , and debug the session value on the first display before doing the refresh ..does the page content stored in the value ??

Comment: sorry for the late response, I've tried this code. When I click the submit button the app_list.php it display nothing. But when I refresh the page it displays the records. Why is that?